# reactjs getting api: Can we avoid using fetch and only use axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch

I am thinking to use axios and not fetch because of the below ease of use

```
axios.post(url,data,auth).then(res => {
        toast("Successful!");
      })
      .catch(err => {
          toast(<pre style={{whiteSpace: 'pre-line' }}>Error!<br></br>{JSON.stringify(err.response['data'])}</pre>);
      });
```

Main advantage:

- status is 2xx then i can show success
- status is not 2xx then i can show the err

but in the fetch it not so easy to do this.

But i found many projects people use fetch inspite the difficulty. But i want to stick to axios.
Will i have to worry about this

Comment: i only used axios in my project. It works fine

Comment: You can make `fetch` do the same thing, but it's entirely up to you (or your team/org) which you use.

Comment: yes, its just my preference. but i wanted to know what coders promote to use more and why

Comment: Fetch API is low-level and native, it supports streams and other recent additions. It is naturally supported in service workers. Adios doesn't have fetch adapter yet and isn't supported in SW. This limits ways in which the app can evolve as PWA. You are free to use any lib you wish and Axios is not the only one. There are high-level abstractions over Fetch like Ky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axios is popular library so you shouldn't to worry about using this. Axios have many advantage on fetch. For example, I like instances in axios.
Here is [list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-fetch-and-axios-js-for-making-http-requests/#:%7E:text=Fetch%20request%20is%20ok%20when,()%20method%20on%20the%20response.) of the advantages and differences.

Comment: So mainly because there is no need to install third party library fetch is used. thats the main advantage or feel more authenticated.